# Can we post the example questions from the definition phase?

Tags: discussion

A few of the example questions that were asked during the [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502?phase=definition)were quite interesting. I'd love to see some of the answers that we get on the site. Some that would interest me:

- Which online resources do you use for protein 3D structure prediction?
- Which assays can be used to detect methylation of DNA?
- How and why does temperature affect photosynthesis?
- What role do histones play in pre-mRNA splicing?
- Many others.

Is there currently a policy in place about this? How should we approach this? What do you think?

Comment: The first one is a list question?

Comment: It can always be rephrased to be more specific.

Comment: but yes otherwise I cant see a problem in posting highly voted definition questions

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with posting most of those questions, but they need to be fleshed out a bit. Currently they are only one sentence, that is a bit short for a good question. Some context and motivation would be nice, though that might be hard in a few cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would love it if you could post some of those questions. I do believe that I have already asked the first in a different form:

[First pass protein structure prediction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1803/389)

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead. Those are interesting questions, they *should* be asked (properly). This might also help to pick up the pace of the site a little.